# "valid intents must be provided for the client"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a discord bot that takes an audio stream URL and outputs it onto a voice chat, but instead I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client. at Client._validateOptions (/home/runner/LaFiestaMalisimaBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:489:13) at new Client (/home/runner/LaFiestaMalisimaBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:78:10) at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/LaFiestaMalisimaBot/index.js:2:16) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)`

This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready to slay')
const player = createAudioPlayer()
  const stream = ("linkhere", { filter: 'audioonly' })
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: "channelidhere",
    guildId: "guildidhere",
    adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
})
connection.subscribe(player)

player.play("urlhere")});

client.login(resource);
```

Comment: You must provide intents for discord.js to use. Look at the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

The only intent you should need should be Guild

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]
});
```

You can read more about gateway intents in the documentation: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents

Comment: "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo

Comment: "ReferenceError: Client is not defined"

Comment: Did you import it?

const { Client, Discord } = require('discord.js');

Comment: @radu-m "ReferenceError: GatewayIntentBits is not defined"

Comment: I corrected my comment you just need:

const { Client, Discord } = require('discord.js');

Comment: @RaduM same error, the gatwayintentbits one.

Comment: Well then you also need to import this one... it is the same principle

Comment: const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Discord } = require('discord.js');

Comment: @RaduM "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')"

Comment: DiscordJS doesn't export any member named `Discord`

Comment: Which DiscordJS Version are you using?